# How to align items in a listView in wpf to be in the center middle of a column?

Tags: c#, wpf

Now the numbers are aligned to the left.

[image: id's aligned to the left by default]

I tried to change the alignment to the center, but it didn't change much.

```
<Window x:Class="wpfMultiThreadListViewUpdate.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="500">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Update" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="10,10,0,0" Click="btnUpdate_Click"/>
        <ListView x:Name="lstvwPeople" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="250" Margin="10,40,0,0">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="100">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I also tried to change the ID Width value to 150 but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the contents of the cell are wrapped in the outer container. For some reason, by default, the WPF developers chose the Left alignment value for the outer container.
You might be happy with a solution that changes the style of the default value for all Items in the ListView:

```xml
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Update" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="10,10,0,0" Click="btnUpdate_Click"/>
        <ListView x:Name="lstvwPeople" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="250" Margin="10,40,0,0">
           <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
               <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                   <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
               </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="100">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

**P.S.** Personally, I prefer to use a DataGrid with the IsReadOnly=true setting for such tasks. It is more convenient and flexible in settings.

Comment: can you show me the full code of the xaml?  where do i put this code in your answer with in my code?

Comment: @SharonHemed, I changed the code in my answer to be more complete.